# How to use pointer from other classes in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, pointers, viewcontroller, scene

I'm immigrating my old ObjectiveC code to swift. In ObjcC had a separate class to handle my Admob activity.
In this class I've created a pointer in the init func, and when changing scene, I could use this pointer to change the location of the ads banner.

```
       @implementation MyAdsSupport

    +(id)ShowAds:(My_Ads_Position)posIndex
    {
        if (_adsBannerPointer == nil)
        {
            _adsBannerPointer = [[KTFAdsSupport alloc]initAds:posIndex];
        }
        else
        {
            [_adsBannerPointer setAdsPosition:posIndex];
        }
        return _adsBannerPointer;
    }
```

In Swift I created the Admob class, and managed to present ads on screen but when I try to call the pointer from another class it returns always nil.
Here is my Swift Code:

```
   var adsPointer: My_Ads_Support!

func initAds(myView: UIViewController, atPos: My_Ads_Position) -> KTF_Ads_Support {


    if adsPointer == nil {
        adsPointer = self
        adsPointer.ShowAds(myView: myView, atPos: atPos)
    }
    else
    {
        print("adsPointer ALIVE")
        adsPointer.setAdsPos( atPos: atPos)
    }
    return self.adsPointer!
}
```

How can I set a pointer in Swift to be able to reach the ads banner from any scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Objective-C code you have *three* methods, the *instance* methods `initAds:` and `setAdsPosition:`, and the *class* method `ShowAds:`. The latter uses a variable, presumably declared `static`, called `_adsBannerPointer`.

Your Swift code is *not* the same. It has two methods, the *instance* methods `initAds` and `setAdsPos`, and one variable, the *instance* variable `adsPointer`.

In Swift class methods are termed *type methods* (as they can belong to classes, structs and enumerations) and are indicated by the use of the keyword `static`, type (class) variables are also indicated with `static`. So to follow your Objective-C model you need something along the lines of:

```
static var adsPointer: My_Ads_Support!

// instance init
init(startingPos : My_Ads_Position) { ... }

// instance set position
fun setAdsPos(atPos : My_Ads_Position) { ... }

static func showAds(myView: UIViewController, atPos: My_Ads_Position) -> KTF_Ads_Support { ... }
```

HTH